The transfer function of an RC band-pass filter circuit


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I want to find the transfer function of the circuit shown in the diagram, ignoring its parameters. The transfer function I derived on my own is shown in the image below. Is this transfer function correct? I would appreciate your assistance.


Transfer function calculation by inspection. Bode plots:


Your answer seems "not consistent" with dimensions (coef of s^2 in denominator).
Made with Maple.
The transfer fonction seems to be this :


Here is a simple method to check whether the result can be correct:
1.) Check if numerator and denominator are dimensionless.
Example: sRC and s²R²C² is OK. But look into s²-term of the denominator. There are two errors.
2.) Check if in case of C2=0 the transfer function reduces to to a first order high-pass.
3.) Check if in case of R2=0 the transer function is still a bandpass function.
EDIT/Added: Recommendation for quick calculation:

Find Vout/V1 with V1 being the voltage across R1 (simple voltage divider).

Find V1/Vin and multiply (Vout/V1)*(V1/Vin)=Vout/Vin


